# Cannot dynamically add new button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm just starting to learn VB and Visual Studio and I've run across a problem.  I've spent the best part of a day trying to find the answer and I have a horrible feeling that it's going to be something very simple that I've over looked.

I'm working on a WPF in Visual Studio 2010 and am trying to dynamically create a button on the main window when a button is clicked (I know, everything I've read tells me this is pretty basic!)  Here's an edited snippet of the code I've written:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles edit.Click

    ...

    Dim newButton As New Button
    newButton.Text = "New Button"
    newButton.Top = 200
    newButton.Left = 20
    Me.Controls.Add(newButton)

    ...

    End Sub
```

To my eyes, this looks perfectly simple and correct, but I'm getting an error:

"'Controls' is not a member of 'myApp.MainWindow'."

Has anybody come across this before or know what the problem is?  Apologies if this does turn out to be a simple fix :)

Answer (score 5):

The error you are getting is telling you that `Controls` does not exist within `MainWindow`. Basically, there is not property by that name accessible from your event handler. If you are working with WPF and `MainWindow` inherits `Window`, then you need to set something within the `Content` property.

The best way to go about this, would be to have some form of container control as the content of the window. You can define this in XAML or in code (via code you should set the `Window.Content` property). Then, you can add more controls to that container. Suggested containers are `Grid`, `Canvas` and `StackPanel`, etc.

I would suggest something like this:

**XAML**

```
<MainWindow ...>

    <StackPanel x:Name="ControlContainer">
        <Button Content="Click me to create buttons!" Click="CreateButton_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</MainWindow>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Private Sub CreateButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim button As New Button()

    ' Initialize the button
    ' ...

    ' Add the button to the stack panel
    Me.ControlContainer.Children.Add(button)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

well MainWindow is not a **form**. create a new project and copy the same code in a button it will work.

you must find out what is the problem with your form control.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing WinForms and WPF coding - these are two different technologies.

[This link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=568007) may help you to add a button at runtime in WPF